# PostgreSQL / PgRouting syntax error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

Using PostgreSQL/PgRouting syntax, I wrote query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('SELECT gid  AS id,
      source::int4 AS source,
      target::int4 AS target,
      cost::float8 AS cost,
      reverse_cost::float8 AS reverse_cost
from network where country='USA'  ',                           
257027,
276521,
true,
true)
```

I got an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USA"
LINE 6:  from network where country='USA'  ',             
ERROR: syntax error at or near "USA"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 226
```

So, I create new field in the network table countryInt and I updated field like this:

```
Update network set countryInt =1 where country='USA'
```

So, my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('SELECT gid  AS id,
    source::int4 AS source,
    target::int4 AS target,
    cost::float8 AS cost,
    reverse_cost::float8 AS reverse_cost
from network where countryInt=1 ',                           
257027,
276521,
true,
true)
```

And now it works.

However, what if I have to put some string in condition, and quotation marks are a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape the single quote with another single quote:

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('SELECT gid  AS id,
      source::int4 AS source,
      target::int4 AS target,
      cost::float8 AS cost,
      reverse_cost::float8 AS reverse_cost
from network where country=''USA''  ',                           
257027,
276521,
true,
true)
```